# VBScript Hide/Unhide Textbox

Tags: vbscript, asp-classic

So I have the following code on my asp page that should hide/unhide a textbox depending on the two conditions and whether or not they are both met.

```
if request.form("Requester_Presenter") = 1 and request.form("Additional_Presenters") = 0 then
    ErrorMessage = ErrorMessage + "<dd>- If you are not a presenter, there must be additional presenters selected so you can provide their contact information in the next step.</dd>"
    document.form.presenters.style.display = "none"
end if

if request.form("Requester_Presenter") = 0 and request.form("Addition_Presenters") = 0 then'do something'
document.form.presenters.style.display = "block"
end if
```

when I run my code however, I get the following error:

```
Microsoft VBScript runtime error '800a01a8' 

Object required: 'document'
```

which says that I am experiencing my error on the line where I set the textbox to display: none; or display:block;

What am I doing wrong here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Classic ASP (vbScript) is a Server side scripting language and what you're trying to do is mix Server side code with client side code (`document` is available in javascript and represent the current loaded page in the DOM)

What you can do, is embed this code inside a script html tag and have it output some javascript :

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    <%
    if request.form("Requester_Presenter") = 1 and request.form("Additional_Presenters") = 0 then
        ErrorMessage = ErrorMessage + "<dd>- If you are not a presenter, there must be additional presenters selected so you can provide their contact information in the next step.</dd>"
    %>
        document.form.presenters.style.display = "none"
   <%
   end if

   if request.form("Requester_Presenter") = 0 and request.form("Addition_Presenters") = 0 then 'do something'
   %>
       document.form.presenters.style.display = "block"
   <% end if %>
</script>
```

Comment: Thanks for the explanation, I was not entirely clear how VBScript operated on an asp page.